# lstinputlisting ignores showlines=true

Tags: listings

I am trying to display some code in my document using `lstinputlisting`. I want to display code written in Stan. I have a separate Stan file which I then call in my Latex document.

Below is a working example. It is not so minimal because of the large preamble. I am worried that something from my preamble might be overriding the `showlines=true` argument and therefore I am pasting my entire preamble here so that you can see. The rest of the document has been reduced to the working example, as well as the Stan code.

For this example to work, you will have to first make a separate file out of the Stan code. That's why I will be pasting two code chunks, one for the Stan code and one for the Latex code.

First, here is the Stan code. The file is named `stan_code.stan`.

```
data {
  real X;
  }

parameters {
  real Y;
}

model {
  X ~ normal(Y, 1);
}
```

Ironically, I am also unable to add the last empty line of code here on Stack Exchange, but please do so manually. My real Stan file contains a last empty line of code.

Here is the code of my Latex file along with the large preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{cl}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{\tablename\ #2}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=myformat,labelsep=period}  
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\alph{subtable}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subtable{}
\makeatletter

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} 

\lstset{
  aboveskip=1ex,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!25},
  basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily\linespread{.9}\selectfont,
  belowskip=1ex,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  framerule=0pt,
  framexrightmargin=0em,
  framexleftmargin=0em,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
  tabsize=2,
  showlines=true
}

\usepackage{lstbayes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{abstract}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}    
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\@M
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=Stan]{stan_code.stan}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I am getting:

[image]

So even though my code contains a last empty line and I use `showlines=true` in the `lstset`, this gets completely ignored and the last empty line gets cut off. Is something overriding this or is there some other problem? How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** The log file can be found here: https://0bin.net/paste/qipTojzM#WVKH-wbIDq7KdT4LyS2goZE4kU7XY6Zt+Ul7H31giHA

Comment: Works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/eghtz.png Can you show your .log file?

Comment: (to make your question more concise you could use the filecontents environment to make a minimal working example which already includes your code file. This way you could also add the empty line at the end)

Comment: Sorry, I have to upload the log somewhere else because it's over the character limit here

Comment: Have a look at pastebin.com and similar services

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Added the link to the log file!

Comment: Thanks! A couple of package aren't the current version, but nothing in particular stands out. To make sure we start from the same page: can you try this file https://pastebin.com/eSEUqeP2 and check if you get an empty line at the end or not?

Comment: Thanks! Do you think you could maybe upload it to 0bin or somewhere else? I currently can't access pastebin as it says waiting on region1.google-analytics.com and it fails to progress further from this

Comment: I posted a temporary answer. Please let me know when you copied the code and I'll delete the answer again

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've copied the code and now the last line seems to be displayed properly

Comment: Ok, then I think the problem might be in your .stan file and not in the latex code

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the lengthy check-up! This is really odd because the file definitely contains a last empty line https://pasteboard.co/gzoPWogzPcaO.png

I know this is no longer a Latex problem, but I don't know where I would inquire further about this problem. I guess I will try Stack Overflow even though it's not really a programming problem.

Comment: maybe some problem with end-of-line characters or something along these lines - not my area of expertise.

Comment: "I am worried that something from my preamble might be overriding the showlines=true argument and therefore I am pasting my entire preamble here so that you can see. " You really don't need to do that, you can easily check before posting whether the problem remains after removing the package, so  just post a minimal example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No I can't easily check, because I have tens of packages loaded and not just 3-4. It's much faster if someone who is an expert already can recognize which package conflicts with something.

Comment: no sorry it is completely unhelpful to people offering to help you to put absolutely no effort in to making a reasonable example,  You have not even fixed multiple calls to the same package, eg `multirow` and deleting packages half at a time means even if you have hundreds of packages you can test them all in just a few runs to get an example with just the packages needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Several points: 1) MWEs are encouraged, but not an official policy of the site, as I understand from Meta; 2) In this example there was nothing about them that makes it harder for the person who tries to help to do the helping; 3) It is still faster for someone who is an expert to detect if there is a package that causes problems than for me to re-run it several times

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and 4) Most importantly, if the problem was due to a conflicting package, then I would have solved it by removing the package for the MWE and thus other future users with a similar problem wouldn't be able to find this question and see what caused the problem, thus also costing them their time with the removal and rerunning of their packages and documents. I am not going to argue about this further.

Comment: No you are wrong. You should not expect every reader to clean up your example fixing things raised on earlier questions before even starting to debug your code. of course it is your post you do not have to follow my advice but  if you make it harder for people to answer you are less likely to get answers